# Favicon not showing up sometimes

Tags: html, css, favicon

I can not find a solution to my issue with the favicon.  I have searched everywhere.  I have a test site and the header is driven by php and inserts the same html header code on all the pages.  I can confirm this just by looking at the source code of the pages in question.  I have tried about all I know what to do

Here is my code in the html header. http://new.franmar.com/confirmation/980

```
<link rel='icon' href='/favicon.png' type='image/png'> 
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='/favicon.png' type='image/png'>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

When I go to the home page (http://new.franmar.com/) I get the icon to show.  And its the same code.

And ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://new.franmar.com/favicon.ico

You have a 404 error there.  Where is this file located?

Comment: Ha, i was using a png and a ico for backup, if that even works.  I removed the last line and it came back.  However, that is odd it appears on certain pages even how it is.